# mysql append local variable inside a cursor

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, cursor

Having a brain fade moment and can't remember how to do the following:

I have a cursor inside a stored procedure that's looping through a table of addresses.
I am trying to build up a string variable of all the addresses found so that once the loop ends I can update a single column in another table with all the addresses found as a single string

Inside my cursor I have the following:

```
SET v_pDetails = CONCAT(v_Type,": ",fnc_get_Address(v_padr),CHAR(13));
```

But all I get in my string is the last record found not the list

So I tried:

```
SET v_pDetails = CONCAT(v_pDetails,v_Type,": ",fnc_get_Address(v_padr),CHAR(13));
```

and

```
SET v_pDetails = v_pDetails 
               + CONCAT(v_pDetails,v_Type,": ",fnc_get_Address(v_padr),CHAR(13));
```

But they give me nothing

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I needed to firstly initialize the string:

```
SET v_pDetails =  '';
```

Then I changed the concat as follows:

```
SET v_pDetails= CONCAT(v_pDetails,v_Type,": ",fnc_get_Address(v_padr),CHAR(13));
```

All now works as expected.